# BIOS update in my HP Pavilion g6 Laptop

Tags: wireless, hp, bios

Is there a way to update my BIOS of HP Pavilion g6 from Ubuntu 15.10? Hp has released the BIOS update only for Windows 7. I don't have windows installed in my laptop right now. So is there any way to update the BIOS through Ubuntu. I want to update my BIOS since my laptop is having WiFi issues. WiFi is not connecting sometimes and a reboot is required. I had the same problem when i was using Windows 8. So I think it could be the BIOS problem not starting the WiFi adapter properly. Please help.

Comment: This is a detailed guide to help flash BIOS on Ubuntu: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318789

Comment: FreeDOS cannot execute .exe files

Comment: The method described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu/1094838#1094838 worked for me on an HP desktop. Short summary: Extract Windows BIOS update file to the directory /boot/efi/EFI/HP/BIOS/New. No USB stick needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you looking for is here : 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIOSUpdate
Scroll down to see about hp

Comment: The link has expired and also this is not an answer. Please, comment it.

Comment: For HP there is only a workaround for website. I can't find anything but all .exe files that too only available under Windows 7.  No proper answer. There is no BIOS upgrade option in BIOS menu for me.