# Flashing UEFI from Ubuntu directly?

Tags: updates, uefi, hp

Is there a way to flash a motherboard from UEFI from Ubuntu directly? I downloaded an [exe from HP.com and ran the self-extractor from Wine](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp57501-58000/sp57762.html). It failed when trying to put it on a USB key. Here is the directory structure after I run the .exe and extract it with Wine.

```
sp57762/
├── BiosUpdate
│   ├── CryptRSA32.efi
│   ├── CryptRSA.efi
│   ├── HpBiosUpdate32.efi
│   ├── HpBiosUpdate32.s09
│   ├── HpBiosUpdate32.s12
│   ├── HpBiosUpdate32.sig
│   ├── HpBiosUpdate.efi
│   ├── HpBiosUpdate.s09
│   ├── HpBiosUpdate.s12
│   └── HpBiosUpdate.sig
├── FirmwareUpdate.exe
├── FreeDOS
│   ├── KERNEL.SYS
│   └── kernels.zip
├── hpqFlash.exe
├── HPUSBFW.exe
├── Installer.exe
├── KERNELS.ZIP
├── ROM.CAB
├── Rompaq
│   ├── 68AHH.BIN
│   ├── config.sys
│   ├── EROMPAQ.EXE
│   ├── EROMPAQ.zip
│   ├── gpl2.txt
│   └── KERNEL.SYS
└── WSSP57762.rtf
```

I just want to know if I can meaningfully throw the 68AHH.BIN or the .efi at the underlying hardware and get something more useful.

## Background

I have an HP laptop, the [instructions to flash](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03101724) the bios are not applicable. My BIOS simply lacks **File > Flash System ROM**, [just like this guy](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Boot-and-Lockup/bios-update-no-option-to-update/td-p/5763564). I can boot the `HpBiosUpdate.efi` from the EFI, but that also doesn't work and it gives me an error though different from the one he got:

> The System Bios Update Failed

I tried multiple different methods, [including this one](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/How-to-flash-BIOS-without-having-HP-Tools-Partition/td-p/533561/page/2).

Comment: I do not have an HP, but I put the new UEFI file in the ESP. The ESP only reads FAT32 partitions and that was the only FAT32 partition I have. My older BIOS systems would read from a FAT32 formatted flash drive, but I have not tried that from UEFI.

Comment: @oldfred I tried that too, I just get `The System Bios Update Failed`. I think you have to boot into `68AHH.BIN` and then give that the `HpBiosUpdate.efi`. It just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could try running the EXE from Windows PE

Comment: I always get nervous when flashing the BIOS from Linux. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux

Comment: I use FreeDOS but no experience with UEFI and flashing BIOS

Comment: For an HP desktop I extracted the *.bin file with /usr/bin/7z and copied it into the ESP under  /boot/efi/EFI/HP/BIOS/New, rebooted and went into the BIOS and selected "Update BIOS Using Local Media". See https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu/1094838#1094838

Answer (score 1):

There are some relatively new tools and protocols that are designed to address this issue, but they require support in the computer's firmware, and that support is still fairly uncommon. You can see if your computer supports this feature by typing:

```
fwupdate -s
```

Unfortunately, the feature is rather poorly documented, so even if your computer supports it, I'm not 100% sure how it works. Based on the scant documentation, I *think* that you pass `fwupdate` the name of a firmware file (such as `firmware.cap`):

```
sudo fwupdate firmware.cap
```

I *think* that this tool is dependent on a matching EFI program, `fwupx64.efi`, which does the actual firmware update when you reboot.

If your system doesn't support this mechanism, then you may just need to follow whatever instructions the manufacturer provides. I have an old HP ProBook 6470b that was particularly obnoxious to update: I had to install Windows on a spare hard disk, in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, and run the firmware update tool from there. Based on the page to which you linked, it looks like your HP may be from a similar era and may need a similar approach -- or some obscure procedure I never discovered.

I have seen systems that provide undocumented, but obvious, firmware update options in their setup utilities that will work when fed the right file extracted from a DOS or Windows `.exe` file provided by the manufacturer. I never discovered such an option on my HP 6470b, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a general way to flash HP consumer machine firmware directly from Linux, but as a second-best, it is at least possible on the machine that I needed to update (an HP Envy 700-060ea) without the use of Windows (e.g. with only Linux installed on the machine).

First I extracted the HP softpaq:

`wine Downloads/sp72302.exe /e /f z:hpbios`

... and then extracted files from the self-extracting zip exe:

`cd hpbios && unzip Kai_8024.exe`

I examined the `hpbios/Flash.bat` which was amongst the files extracted...

The batch file included a commandline which updates the Intel ME firmware with the file `ME9_1482.BIN`.  The HP tool included the Windows ME flashing tool "FWUpdLcl.exe", but it should be possible to flash the same file with Intel's EFI flash tool (`FWUpdLcl.efi`) from the UEFI shell.

Newer ME versions can also be updated directly from Linux using the Linux flashing tool from the "Intel CSME System Tools" `FWUpdate/LINUX64/FWUpdLcl`, but I wasn't able to find an equivalent for ME 9.x systems.

The main BIOS file in this case is called `KAI_8024.bin` - I copied this to the efi boot partition into the `EFI/HP/BIOS/New/` folder then I then rebooted the machine (into an EFI shell) and ran the EFI binary: `EFI/HP/BiosUpdate/HpBiosUpdate.efi` from the shell command line.

n.b. instead of using the EFI shell, you can probably run it directly from grub using the `chainloader` command with the appropriate path to HpBiosUpdate.efi, followed by the `boot` command.

To obtain the EFI shell (open source included in the TianoCore project, as well as various forks), you can use one of the many online tutorials to either install an EFI shell boot entry from grub, or create a bootable USB drive etc.  I used: https://github.com/tianocore/edk/blob/master/Other/Maintained/Application/UefiShell/bin/x64/Shell_Full.efi ).

n.b. The `EFI/HP/BiosUpdate/` directory was factory-installed, but you can probably find a suitable copy in an HP support file download (e.g. see the original question for a possible source - although I don't know if there are different versions of `HpBiosUpdate.efi` for different machine types).

`HpBiosUpdate.efi` looks for a firmware update file in `EFI/HP/BIOS/New/` and writes out a log file at `EFI/HP/BiosUpdate/HpBiosUpdate.log` with debug messages, as well as displaying a simple mouse-driven GUI.  After the flashing was completed, the machine power cycled several times, and then after booting Linux, the expected new BIOS version `80.24` was displayed in the output of `dmidecode` under Linux (previously `80.13` was installed).

The log file is reasonably clear and useful, so I recommend viewing that file from Linux, to check that the contents look sensible.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated, Ubuntu supports firmware updates on a number of machines. In my particular case, my Dell XPS 9560 has received at least one BIOS firmware update since the start of this year (I'm running Gnome Ubuntu 17.04).

Interestingly, these updates are **not** picked up through the normal software update process (*e.g.*, `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`).

Instead, I've only seen firmware update checks made via the Details GUI (which is part of the `gnome-control-center` application). By clicking the Check for Updates button I'll see relevant firmware updates.

To date, firmware updates have worked with no problems.