# How to restore HP BIOS from Ubuntu?

Tags: uefi, hp

I deleted windows 8 and installed Ubuntu, but today I realize that I cannot access the BIOS, I decided to install windows 7, since ubuntu freezes my screen I have to turn off the computer to use it again.

The only information I get when I turn on the device is F1-Continue F10-Bios Configuration, but pressing F10 does not open the settings, access the Ubuntu system, and I tried some alternatives such as controlling the windows b key, among other key combinations , but I can't access the BIOS settings.

I found a post here, I followed all the steps, but the last line of code is not compatible, I get an error, the line that marks the error is:

```
sudo cp *.bin /boot/efi/EFI/HP/BIOS/New
```

The error:

```
cp: cannot stat '*.bin': No such file or directory
```

The ubuntu version

```
lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
```

The tutorial I am following some help to solve this problem.

[How to perform a HP BIOS upgrade with only Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu?noredirect=1)

Comment: Your error indicates it cannot find the `*.bin` files you are trying to copy to a directory I assume is on your EFI partition. The command will assume you used `cd` (change directory) into whichever directory those files you want to copy are found, otherwise you should provide the path as part of the filename `*.bin`*  (eg. /home/.../*.bin`)   *I didn't look at your links*

Comment: If this is a laptop and your keyboard has an `Fn` button, you may need to hold that and then press the F keys to enter bios.

Comment: Also if your Ubuntu is laggy and constantly freezing, it may be due to a recent bug related to swap. So I would recommend sticking with 18.04 LTS which runs more stable and doesn’t have this problem.

Comment: @darksky If it is a laptop, but what is the FN key I do not see it on my keyboard

Comment: @darksky I would have to re-enter reinstall, but this still worries me that I cannot access the BIOS settings

Comment: Do you have an external keyboard you can hook up to your laptop via USB?

Comment: @Pepe the FN key looks like this http://blog.drivethelife.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/esc-fix-fn-key-not-working-laptop.png

Comment: this was my procedre to apply the F21 bios for my  15m bq121dx
(ah, I just discovered that shift+enter gives a new line for these comments here)
https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp96501-97000/sp96792.exe
sp9672.exe

Comment: "go into windows and extract to HP usb stickv into the NEW folder.
this stick will not be on the boot menu, but hotkey and boot holding down power+b or all 4 arrows gets there
note too that continue button is touchscrfeen only, but one press of the power button did it." my touchscreen at the time was broken. and not too that there was a procedure on how to get the HP BIOS  USB stick created, using windows, and ONLY windows and HPs procedure. not for the faint hearted.