# How to update HP BIOS when I can not find the update

Tags: updates, hp, bios

I have been updating BIOS firmware for a little while now. So far it only has been on Dell Desktops using USB media, but I was looking into updating the firmware on my HP laptop (Ubuntu Installation)

Product: HP 2000 Notebook PC. Serial Number: 5CG32730CZ.

I tried finding the BIOS firmware update file using the official HP website. However, when I enter the serial number for my laptop, the HP website comes back with "can not find any drivers for this product", so how am I supposed to update my BIOS? (BIOS F.47).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to manually select an operating system (Windows ) and just claim Windows 7 64 bit.  Then the downloads all show up, look under BIOS tab for the F48 download.
[Here's the link for the BIOS for your machine](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-2000-200-notebook-pc-series/5091493/model/5118923)

Comment: I'm going to try this thanks a lot will accept your answer if it works

Comment: Alright new problem my computer does not show a update BIOS option in my BIOS settings how would i go about updating?

Comment: There is a BIOS tool listed, try that.  It's up to the vendor what they supply, DOS executable, or worse case, a Windows executable. Freedos works if it's a DOS executable. Better ask a different question, others may have a solution.

Comment: I'm going to do some research thanks for all your help did not know HP would be this confusing thank God for other manufacturing companies.

Comment: After this, you'll have to follow these instructions to use the .exe: https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu