# Ubuntu 20.04 HP Pavilion installation problem

Tags: system-installation, hp, 20.04

I've been trying to install Ubuntu on my computer for a long time. I have an HP Pavilion 15-cb005nt device with Windows 10 64-bit installed. I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10 on the same computer before. I had the same problem. At the *Installation type* screen I choose the *Erase the entire disk and install Ubuntu* option. It comes to the loading screen. After half of it says copy to disk is finished wait, and the computer crashes in the meantime.

I looked at the questions asked HP support. The following suggestion was made to a person who encountered the same problem. Enter the BIOS. Legacy mode is on. Disable Secure Boot. The same as my BIOS settings, but there was no solution and it got stuck at the same place. I have an Nvidia 1050 graphics card, 240GB SSD and 1TB HDD.  I got the same error when I wanted to install it on both disks. I haven't been able to load Ubuntu for 1 years.

Comment: I have faced this as well.  I am not an expert.  Others will fix my posts. I would download and install Easus Partition master home edition. Then make an ext4(Easus may only allow ext3 which is fine.  You can change it later)  partition for Ubuntu. Do this by shrinking the windows storage partition first.  Then create a new ext4/ext3 partition and name it ubuntu(optional). Note its size approximately so you don't wipe out windows later.  After that is all done try again and you may see the partition you need to install ubuntu.

Comment: thanks @walttheboss i will try your suggestion.  However, when doing disk formatting on my computer, when it copies the upload files, it says please wait and the computer crashes.

Comment: OK to clarify. Do you want dual-boot(Windows and Ubuntu) or just Ubuntu. If you have an encrypted Win 10 Pro install you can repartition but Windows will be dead unless you have the encryption key. Don't do the formatting from the Install disk.  Do that from Easus while logged into Windows.  Easus is a windows program. If that fails you can make a live disk of GParted and do the parittioning there. Or instead of doing the install just click on "Try Ubuntu"  You may partition from there.

Comment: I want only ubuntu installed on my computer.  I said Windows 10 is installed.  I wrote this in the sense that there is no problem with my computer.  There should be no windows installation though.  Windows is loading but Ubuntu is not.  I don't want two operating systems on my computer.  Ubuntu only.  I want to get rid of windows operating system completely

Comment: perfectly clear.  I think then that booting to a live gparted and wiping out the windows first may help.  I would in that case create a brand new gpt partition table on the disk. Then creata 100 MB fat32 partition first(to the left fo the disk). Then one big ext4 root ( / ) partition about 30 GB on the SSD.  Then the rest of the ssd for /home.  Partition the 1 TB drive as /media and ext4.  After that is all done you will NOT have the necessary mbr on the first partition. Now boot-repair and install the MBR with that. THEN install Ubuntu.

Comment: Many systems need UEFI update and SSD firmware update. Often easier from Windows but most can update by downloading the update file, save to FAT32 partition and directly update. You will need nomodeset boot parameter. If newer system, UEFI is prefered, but HP does not make it easy. https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu/1234098#1234098 &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved my problem. You can find the solution for the solution at the following link. https://forum.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?topic=60909.msg653445#msg653445

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it on safe graphic mode. I got a HP Pavilion 15-cx0010ca and that did it for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved my problem. You can find the solution for the solution at the following link. https://forum.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?topic=60909.msg653445#msg653445

Comment: Hi @HalimAsa could you post your solution in English? I followed your link but could not understand anything. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Alfonso  https://halimasa.com.tr/purple-screen-freezing-issue-during-ubuntu-installation/
i hope it works