# New Laptop freezes

Tags: freeze

I bought a new notebook (HP Pavilion 15-Dk0201ng Gaming Notebook) few days back and I did single boot with Ubuntu 20.04. It was a new laptop with no OS installed when I bought it.  I have not installed any other things except Ubuntu in the notebook. But when I right click on the desktop and click on one of the options, say Settings, the laptop freezes. Neither keyboard nor touchpad works. I have to press the power button to turn it off and on. When it then turns on, the freezing problem disappears. However, the problem appears again as I said, when I right click on the desktop and click on one of the options.

Can anybody suggests me how can this problem be solved ?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from HP? and if SSD, updated SSD firmware? https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu/1234098#1234098 & 
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/How-to-update-BIOS-on-Linux/m-p/5441775#M1205498

Comment: I think I have not updated SSD firmware. I single booted with Ubuntu 18.04 too but the problem persisted. However, when I single boot with Windows 10, the freezing problem is not observed.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to answer the question with this much information. All you can do is to narrow the field in which we can look for the problem.

As you have bought this laptop recently and aren't sure that its hardware is okay. You should run the diagnostics from the BIOS.

If the problem isn't found, Open the System Monitor and observe the usage of the CPU, RAM, and storage. Let the System Monitor run and make the computer freeze and unfreeze. Find out which resources are going to 100%. Most of the time the storage disc is the bottleneck.