# How can I make a Windows PE bootable USB from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, live-usb, iso, wimtools

I am running Ubuntu, but I need to boot from Windows PE so that I can install a firmware update (only available as a Win32 `exe`).

I tried following steps [from this Web Upd8 guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/how-to-create-bootable-windows-pe-iso.html) but the resulting USB is not bootable:

1. `sudo apt install wimtools` (required for mkwinpeimg, below)
2. [Download Microsoft WAIK ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753)
3. `sudo mount KB3AIK_EN.iso $HOME/waik`
4. `mkwinpeimg --iso --waik-dir=$HOME/waik winpe.iso --overlay=/path/to/exe/folder`
5. Write `winpe.iso` to USB drive with [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) (also tried [mkusb](https://launchpad.net/%7Emkusb/+archive/ubuntu/unstable))

How can I copy the ISO to the USB drive **and** make it bootable?

Comment: might be relevant? https://www.onetransistor.eu/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html

Comment: HP UEFI update - extract .bin from .exe file and copy into FAT32 partition.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu/1234098#1234098 & 
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/How-to-update-BIOS-on-Linux/m-p/5441775#M1205498