# Upgrade BIOS Lenovo Ideapad 330 IGM

Tags: bios

My Lenovo Ideapad 330 IGM runs on Ubuntu 20.04
The BIOS is 7xcn37ww.
The new BIOS is 7xcn41ww which I downloaded from the Lenovo website and is stored in Downloads as 7xcn41ww.exe
Is it possible to install this .exe file onto my Ideapad without installing Windows? Windoows wants €145 top download Win10.
Appreciate your insights and time on this.

Comment: You can actually install windows without activating - some  features are disabled (eg some personalisations), but not many - so you could run a temporary windows installation in order to update the bios.

Comment: Similar to these: HP UEFI update - extract .bin from .exe file and copy into FAT32 partition.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/539120/how-to-perform-a-hp-bios-upgrade-with-only-ubuntu/1234098#1234098 & 
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/How-to-update-BIOS-on-Linux/m-p/5441775#M1205498